# Проверка пунктуации (2)

Tags: пунктуация

> Можно продолжить эту тему дальше -- она очень велика и предоставляет большой объем информации и подводных камней для рассуждения -- тут как решишь ты, -- но лучше пока взяться за другую тему, близкую к этой.

Волнует, как правильно обособить приложение "но это как решишь ты" внутри другого приложения "она очень велика...". Наверное, я тут что-то намудрил...

Answer (score 1):

Предлагается в качестве варианта:

Можно продолжить эту тему дальше **(она очень велика и предоставляет большой объем информации и подводных камней для рассуждения — тут как решишь ты)**, но лучше пока взяться за другую тему, близкую к этой.

Вставная конструкция (БСП) заключена в скобки и состоит из двух предложений, второе предложение является присоединительным и обособлено с помощью тире.

Comment: Спасибо! А мой вариант корректен?

Comment: В Вашем варианте  две вставки, обособленные тире, поэтому конструкция сложно читается (мне такие не встречались). Если  всё-тки хотите оставить тире, то можно второе обособление заменить запятой: "Можно продолжить эту тему дальше — она очень велика и предоставляет большой объем информации и подводных камней для рассуждения,  тут как решишь ты, — но лучше пока взяться за другую тему, близкую к этой".